# httptest http://tools.maxcdn.com/http Nginx does not answer

Tags: 14.04, nginx, mongodb

My Ubuntu Server:

> Ubuntu 14.04 x64 1GB of RAM , 30GB SSD Drives

I add MongoDB server nginx on Ubuntu.

Working on my website.

My problem now httptest creatng ( http://tools.maxcdn.com/http )
Nginx does not answer .
My websites `www.altinfiyatlariyukselecekmi.com`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your index.php request timeout, so you can't test with maxcdn tool,  but you can [test with a "not found" page](http://tools.maxcdn.com/http?d1=www.altinfiyatlariyukselecekmi.com/index.html&d2=www.baidu.com/index.html), such as `www.altinfiyatlariyukselecekmi.com/index.html`, but I like you need fix the issue of your website, maybe a database connect timeout or nginx upstream timeout?